# PowerShell Script to Delete Everything on a drive except hidden and select directories and anything below them

Tags: windows, powershell

Okay so I am trying to keep a drive, specifically D, completely clear of anything on a server except for select directories and their children

This is what I have so far:

```
   Get-ChildItem -Path "D:\" -Exclude "DirApple", "DirBanana", "Dir Cherry", "Script", "TEST" | foreach ($_) {
       "CLEANING :" + $_.fullname
       Remove-Item $_.fullname -Force -Recurse
       "CLEANED... :" + $_.fullname
   }
```

This works great if my path is D:\TEST\ (I replicated everything in D under D test including what I wanted removed), but if my path is D:\ it does not work at all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-Exclude` for `Get-ChildItem` only excludes filenames, not directory names.  For this reason try using Get-Item instead for this problem.  When combined with a WildCard for the path, this will give you the desired result.

```
 Get-Item -Path "D:\*" -Exclude "DirApple", "DirBanana", "Dir Cherry", "Script", "TEST" | foreach ($_) {
       "CLEANING :" + $_.fullname
       Remove-Item $_.fullname -Force -Recurse
       "CLEANED... :" + $_.fullname
   }
```

#### Why do I have to do this?

The `-Exclude` param for `Get-ChildItem` is meant to exclude only Files, not directories themselves, as seen in the help:

```
> help dir -Parameter Exclude

 -Exclude <String[]>
   Omits the specified items. The value of this parameter qualifies the Path parameter. 
   Enter a path element or pattern, such as "*.txt".
```

Really just a case of not using the very best tool for the job, though you were close!

#### Why'd I need to add a * to the path?

If you look at the help for `-Exclude` for `Get-Item`, you'll note that (emphasis mine):

> The Exclude parameter is effective only when the command **includes
>   the contents of an item 
>        such as C:\Windows***, where the wildcard character specifies the contents of the 
>        C:\Windows directory.

This is why we had to add a WildCard to the Path.